# Android instantiation of a service throug bindService()

Tags: android, service, android-service

I got a problem with binding a service:
I use following code:

```
protected void onCreate(){
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mService != null)
                               Log.e(TAG, "is instantiated (onClick)!");
            });
}

protected void onStart(){
   super.onStart();
   bindService(new Intent(this, HostService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   if(mService == null)
      Log.e(TAG, "is null (onStart)!");
}
...
```

After starting my activity "is null (onStart)!" is printed in LogCat.
When I click the button "is instantiated (onClick)!" is printed.
Why bindService() doesnt instantiate my service-instance mService directly and how can I solve the problems referring to this?

thx & regards

Answer (score 0):

> Why bindService() doesn't instantiate my service-instance mService directly

`bindService()` is asynchronous, like many operations in Android, so it occurred after your test in onStart.

> how can I solve the problems referring to this?

Put your business logic in `onServiceConnected()` of your `ServiceConnection`, instead of immediately after the `bindService()` call.

Here is an example of the ServiceConnection code:

```
private ServiceConnection sConn;
private Messenger messenger;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Service Connection to handle system callbacks
    sConn = new ServiceConnection() {
         @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            messenger = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // We are conntected to the service
            messenger = new Messenger(service);
        }
    };

    // We bind to the service
    bindService(new Intent(this, ConvertService.class), sConn,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

This is from Francesco Azzola's [good example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-bound-service-ipc-with-messenger.html).

Comment: ok that works,  but I have to do some ui stuff in onServiceConnected(). So I send a Message to a handler implemented in my activity (the handling of the message should now run on the Ui thread), but I get following exception: nullpointerexception at textview.checkforrelayout

That's a bit confusing ..?

Comment: @user2224350: "but I have to do some ui stuff in onServiceConnected()" -- `onServiceConnected()` is called on the main application thread. "That's a bit confusing ..?" -- you are welcome to start another StackOverflow question where you post your code, your stack trace, and how they match up (i.e., which lines of the code are referred to from the stack trace).